# Integration of an expression yields wrong result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I'm trying to find a general expression for the definite integral of

```
 Cos[2 h phi - 2 h theta] G0 (Cos[(v π)/6 - theta] K1 + 
Cos[(v π)/2 - 3 theta] K3) (Cos[(k π)/6 - theta] K1 + 
Cos[(k π)/2 - 3 theta] K3)
```

with respect to `theta`, from `0` to `2 π`, where `h`, `v`, `k` are non-negative integers and `phi` is supposed to be a variable. However, the expression

```
Integrate[ Cos[2 h phi - 2 h theta] G0 
  (Cos[(v π)/6 - theta] K1 + 
  Cos[(v π)/2 - 3 theta] K3) 
  (Cos[(k π)/6 - theta] K1 + 
  Cos[(k π)/2 - 3 theta] K3), {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> {h ∈ Integers , v ∈ Integers , 
 k ∈ Integers , h >= 0 , v >= 0 , k >= 0}]
```

yields a function that is not existent if I plug in `h=0`, even though a constant term should come out. The same is true for `h=1`. Does anyone see where I'm making a mistake? I'm using Wolfram Mathematica 10.0.

Comment: If you can try without subscripts, then if it still does not work, please post your input. Hard to even read code with subscripts. No need to use Subscripts.

Answer (score 1):

You should take the limits, not plug in values:

```
expr=G0*(K3*Cos[(k*Pi)/2 - 3*theta] + K1*Cos[(k*Pi)/6 - theta])*
     Cos[2*h*phi - 2*h*theta]*(K3*Cos[3*theta - (Pi*v)/2] + 
     K1*Cos[theta - (Pi*v)/6]);

r = Integrate[expr, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}]; 
Limit[r, h -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Limit[r, h -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use some values

```
Limit[r, h -> 1] /. {K1 -> 1, K2 -> 2, K3 -> 3, v -> 4, G0 -> 5, phi -> 6, k -> 7} // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare to just pluggin in `h=0` and `h=1`

[image: Mathematica graphics]